# Transparent login through URL

Tags: java, security, authentication, spring-security

I'm gonna modify two different webapps, aka "Foo" and "Bar".

They both run under **https**, the first at `https://example.com/foo` and the latter at `https://another.com/bar`.

**My goal is to put a link at Foo, so I can login automatically at Bar.**

Something like this:

`<a href="https://another.com/bar/auth?token=das456s5a4sda2121asae">Click</a>`

The apps are hosted on different servers, but they both have access to the same database.

Given the scenario above, what should I consider before authenticating users using URL parameters?

As an example, I will need to generate the token. Should I just encrypt user + expiration date? Any other advices on auth token generation?

I *could* enable CORS, but I would leave that as a last resort.

Not sure if that is relevant, but *Bar* uses *Spring-Security*

Answer (score 1):

In order to have proper security you need to use some additional service as CAS (Central Authentication Service, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service)  for you SSO (single sign-on).

E.g. you can use http://www.jasig.org/cas.

If you proceed with pre-auth links with tokens,

- anyone who has link, can login to your site
- you have to duplicate the same mechanism implementation for every your site